# Show Element & ClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/AKuHuju/1/edit

I wonder if it's possible to grab the name of the element upon an onclick event.
I'm not talking about the class or id name. I'm talking literally the element name like `div` for example.

Is this possible? If so how would this be done?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.elm-name').click(function() {
    $('.container *').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
       $('.findclassname').val($(this));
    });
  });

  $('.elm-classname').click(function() {
    $('.container *').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
       $('.findclassname').val($(this).attr('class'));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: [`this.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName) gives you the tag name of an element.

Comment: `this.tagName` and `this.className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second click event change:

```
$('.findclassname').val($(this).attr('class'));
```

to

```
$('.findclassname').val(this.nodeName);
```

to get the element's name.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tqqxD/)**

Comment: According to this (http://aleembawany.com/2009/02/11/tagname-vs-nodename/) article nodeName has wider support than tagName. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to get `tagName` here:

```
$(this).prop("tagName")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ueyLU/)

or just `this.tagName` is fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.elm-name').click(function() {
    console.log(this.tagName)// This whould give you the tag name.
});
```